# Rails 3.2 - Allowing HTTP Requests from .NET Client Application

Tags: c#, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, httpwebrequest

I've developed a website using Ruby on Rails, and I have product information stored in the website's database. How might I go about retrieving information about a specific product using a C# client application? I have my Product model set up with the following route:

```
resources :products
```

In C#, I've tried the following code to retrieve product information for a product whose ID is 32:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://127.0.0.1:3000/products/32");

request.Method = "GET";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

String text;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

However, this basically just stores the entire HTML code of the page in the "text" String. How would I be able to retrieve just the product information in XML or JSON format? I believe I need to make some changes in my Rails app, and I found a link from 2011 that recommends using RABL, but I'm not sure if there is a better way of creating an API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you open that url in a browser what you get?

Comment: Hi Gusman! When I open up the URL in a browser, it brings me to the "show" action of the Products controller, which just displays the product details page.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, try to put in your c# request content type "application/json"

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Ok, found it, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html look at the json renderer

Comment: Hi Gusman, and thank you for the link. I would like to render the HTML page when the user visits the URL but would also like JSON or XML information to be sent in the request when an API call is made to either of these formats. Would you happen to know how I might implement that sort of functionality?

Comment: Yes, the standar way is through the content type, if the client sets the content type to application/json then you serve the result with the json renderer, in other case you serve through normal renderer. Don't know how it's done in Ruby, I'm from c#, but it should be easy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gusman's help, I've managed to figure it out!

I've changed my C# code to the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://127.0.0.1:3000/products/32.xml");

request.Method = "GET";

request.ContentType = "application/xml";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

String text;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I added the ".xml" extension to the URL in the CreateHttp method. This way, the regular HTML page will not be loaded; only the XML page will be loaded. As a result of doing this, I had to handle the different format in Rails. Here's what the end of my "show" action in the Products controller looks like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml { render :xml => @product }
end
```

This allows the handling of XML GET requests. I have yet to work on the POST part, but I'm assuming it wouldn't be too different.

Thanks again for all of the help!